Parts of model do not deform when joined to the properly deforming base
I'm rigging a model of clone trooper armor, and I've run into a problem. When I merge the armor and undersuit, and then parent it to the armature, the undersuit moves, but the armor itself doesn't. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

The undersuit is properly weighted but the armor isn’t. The join operation just merges the meshes into the same object. It does not merge vertex properties.

Separate the armor with AltP, select the undersuit, shift select the armor, switch to Weight Paint mode, go into Weights > Transfer Weights, in the pop-up panel choose Source Layers Selection > By Name, join the armor back to the undersuit.
Also doable with the Edit > Data Transfer modifier, separate the meshes, give the modifier to the armor, choose the undersuit as Source, enable Vertex Data and Vertex Groups, click on Generate Data Layers, apply the modifier, join the armor back to the undersuit.
In your case as the armor is made of rigid pieces, maybe you should directly assign these pieces to the correct vertex group. First remove the piece from all groups:

Then assign to the correct group:


That also brings up a new problem. When I pose it, the armor stretches and compresses, and doesn't act like armor.

Maybe make sure that the normals are correctly flipped before the data transfer? If it still not good could you share your file or show some screenshots?

The link to my file: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1PNPOxIIQvbn8nSL9zFRrTuSZcvrseVTF

As the armor seems to be a very rigid one, why don't you simply select each part and assign it to the correct vertex group with the Assign button?

The armor is an individual model, and not just separate pieces(excluding the helmet). But if it is, then where is the Assign button?(I'm newer to blender)

I can also send the file before merging the armor and undersuit. Here: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=15b5XNEaBBsowbgFemuh7EmhPgXBHkg9C

I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

For the individual pieces, do you separate them from the main armor? I'm saying this because when I select all of the vertices for the armor piece, it doesn't show the vertex groups.

Keep them within the same object, I've edited my answer, you first need to remove the pieces from all groups (the vertex groups operations are available in the Data panel)

When I select the body mesh in the mesh editor, the vertex groups show up, but the armor disappears. Is it okay if you send video footage?

ok let me see?............

Or you can send the .blend file for the fixed version. That can also work.

I managed to figure it out. I just have to separate all the parts(via the loose split action), and then parent them to each of the bones.

That's another way of doing it  ;)
